# Dict with list of values convert to np.array object with dtype=int32

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary `{0: [], 1: [], ...}`. The length of every list is different.
How to convert such a dictionary to `np.array` object?
I want to get such a structure: `array([[],[],..., dtype=int32)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, putting the dict into the numpy array works. Also putting the listed values into the array works.

```
import numpy as np

d = {0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 6, 7]}
arr = np.array(d)
print(arr)
li = d.values()
print(li)
arr2 = np.array(li)
print(arr2)
```

Comment: But that doesn't produce a `int32` array.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this ?

```
np.array(list(d.values()))
```

ouput

```
array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
```

Comment: Yes, but it gives me array(dict_values([[], [], []...])).

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are of different lengths you could use a [`np.ma.MaskedArray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html):

```
import numpy as np

maxlen = max(len(lst) for lst in d.values())   # maximum length of all value-lists

arr = np.ma.MaskedArray(np.zeros((len(d), maxlen), dtype='int32'), 
                        mask=True, 
                        dtype='int32')

for line, lst in d.items():
    arr[line, :len(lst)] = lst

# In case the "keys" of your dictionary don't represent the "rows" you need to
# use another (more robust) approach:
# for idx, (line, lst) in enumerate(sorted(d.items())):
#     arr[idx, :len(lst)] = lst
```

For example:

```
d = {0: [], 1: [1], 2: [1, 2]}
```

Gives an `arr` like this:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- --]
 [1 --]
 [1 2]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True]
 [False  True]
 [False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

It won't be the same as having empty lists but NumPy doesn't support ragged arrays so `MaskedArray` is one of the possible ways to "simulate" them. For most purposes they will behave like an "ragged array". :)